# Idiom for being watched after your bad actions

Tags: idiom-requests, translation

There's an idiom in Argentina translated as "To be in the chapel". It means that you'll be closely watched for a period of time to be sure you won't repeat errors, bad actions or behaviors recently done.
It's something mothers normally say to teenagers.

Is there an analogous idiom in English?

Comment: To be in the doghouse means you're in trouble. To be under the microscope means you're being spied on for your recent mistakes.

Comment: There are idioms like "in [special measures](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/special-measures)" but that's more a formal thing than a parental warning.

Comment: @YosefBaskin If OP is from Argentina, they will recognize "under the microscope" as "debajo de la lupa".  Is this what they are after?

Comment: @Kirt I think the expression in Spanish which expresses the idea of being watched would be ''estar bajo la lupa''.  'Debajo de la lupa'' sounds different to me.

Comment: @HollisWilliams I'm not a native speaker and will certainly cede the details, but my general question remains.  If this connotes what OP wants, then "under the microscope" is a good analogy.

Comment: @Kirt I agree but I guess ''under the microscope'' could also just be very close scrutiny in general, whereas OP wants ''person is under a watchful eye and being scrutinized because of bad behavior etc.''

Comment: @HollisWilliams Yeah that's pretty specific

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*On probation* is an idiomatic expression that can be used. Note that this expression has different senses and [*Merriam Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20probation) lists the relevant sense as below:

> being watched for a period of time during which one must behave well in order not to be seriously punished after having made a serious mistake or done something bad
>
> He was on *probation* for cheating. 
> The student was ***put/placed on probation*** for copying test answers.

---

You've also mentioned:

> It's something mothers normally say to teenagers.

It doesn't exactly cover *being watched* but "**You are grounded!**" is an expression mothers say to their children for punishment when they are not allowed to go out and required to stay home after they've done something bad. The strategy is called *time-out* in parenting. Although, I've offered "on probation" also as it has the exact meaning and can be used in different contexts. I believe the Spanish idiom is *estar en capilla* and it has different usages depending on the context.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've heard a mom say this to a teen, maybe some families. Though I had a period where I received 'demerits'. Once someone overheard one being given and was like, 'What is that?', I'm like, smh, 'don't ask'

Comment: Well, parents usually use time-outs as a disciplining strategy and they can say "You are grounded!", but "on probation" has the right meaning and can be used in different contexts.

Comment: I think "to be on probation" really fits the exact meaning. I had thought in that option myself, but I couldn't find in Google if it was a known idiom for that situation. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that "**on probation**" is a very close equivalent, too. "Era el tiempo previo o de espera inmediatamente antes de tan importante **prueba**"[--etimologias.dechile.net](https://etimologias.dechile.net/Expresiones/?Estar-en-capilla), having a similar etymological root.

Comment: Note that "You are grounded" is usually a [speech act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act), and in that respect is quite different.

Comment: Come on, how can you mention "On probation", without a gratuitous reference to "[Double Secret Probation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tfK_3XK4CI) !!

Answer (score 25):

***Keeping someone on a short leash*** is a way of saying they are being closely supervised or controlled in some way to make sure they don't do something bad. It doesn't necessarily mean they have already done something wrong, but there is at least some potential/expectation that things may go poorly if they're not watched closely. It often connotes not just supervising someone, but also limiting their freedom to limit the damage they can cause.

Answer (score 21):

"***To be on thin ice***" or "***to be skating on thin ice***" is what I think you are looking for. It's used in a similar context (mother to teenager) to mean "if I catch you screwing up one more time, there will be hell to pay."

A quick Internet search of this idiom might say "to be in a precarious or risky situation," which is true, but it is mostly used as a sort of threat. (Un)surprisingly, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=on%20thin%20ice) actually captures the connotation and nuance the best I think: its example is of a child being "on thin ice" when her mother sees her report card.

Another example:
-"Hey man call out sick and we'll go skiing tomorrow"
-"Aww I wish I could, but I'm already on thin ice with my boss after the crap I pulled last week"

In media: ("[Snatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXTMngCaRxE&t=93s)" 2000)
Watch the whole clip for more context, but you get the idea of how it can be used as a threat.

Answer (score 10):

You could [watch them like a hawk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/watch-like-a-hawk) (or say that they are being watched like a hawk, however you want to word it).

From the Cambridge Dictionary,

> to watch someone all the time, usually to make sure they do not do something bad:
>
> When I was at home, mum and dad watched me like a hawk.

Comment: This captures the feeling of being intensely monitored, but it feels more proactive to me, instead of the desired reactive observation. If I heard "Alice hated screwups, so she watched Bob like a hawk," I would assume that she was watching to prevent screwups, not because there had been one.

Comment: Why would the parents watch them when they were home if there wasn't already a reputation? It can be used either way.

Answer (score 2):

**[Keep an eye on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-your-eye-on-someone#google_vignette)**

> If someone has their eye on you, they are watching you carefully to see what you do.

It can be a benign expression, to keep an eye on an elderly relative shows care and concern. However, it’s normal usage is to watch closely for wrongdoing.